# Is there any way to make a custom clock of the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In Xcode 6.2 Beta, just few of UI components could be added into watch interface.
Is it possible to customise an analog clock ??

Answer (score 2):

WatchKit is not really designed for this.  There are somethings you may be able to do that are work arounds, but there is a good chance it will be rejected.  See this thread on the Apple developer forums for much more discussion on this. In the WatchKit forums Apple links to this thread under their FAQs.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254629?tstart=15

Answer (score 1):

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) state:

> 10.7 Watch Apps whose primary function is telling time will be rejected